# Plotting two polygons in one graph

Tags: maple

How can I plot two polygons in one graph in maple?
I currently have:

```
display(polygon([[0, 0], [2, 0], [1,1]], 
color = red), 
scaling = constrained);
```

But this only plots one **polygon**, in this case it is a **triangle**, but i want to have two **triangles** next to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define the polygons first and then display them:

```
  g1 := polygon([[0, 0], [2, 0], [1,1]], color = red);
  g2 := polygon([[0, 0], [4, 0], [1,1]], color = blue);
  display(g1, g2);
```

Comment: That makes sense, thank you very much. Can I also ask, if I wanted to add a line, which would represent a light ray, and this line "reflecting back" at a certain angle, do you know how I would do this? Thanks again for your help

Comment: You're welcome, could you mark this as the answer?. Thanks. About the new question...the first thought is to use trigonometry calculations to find the coordinates of the end point knowing the angle, but it's more mathematical issue than a programming one...